# Testing SQL table-valued parameters in sqlmock

Tags: sql-server, go, go-sqlmock

I have a function that is designed to insert a large number of elements into an MSSQL database using a table-valued parameter and a procedure.

```
func (requester *Requester) doQuery(ctx context.Context, dtos interface{}) error {
    conn, err := requester.conn.Conn(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer func() {
        if clErr := conn.Close(); clErr != nil {
            err = clErr
        }
    }()

    tx, err := conn.BeginTx(ctx, &sql.TxOptions{Isolation: sql.LevelRepeatableRead, ReadOnly: false})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer func() {
        if p := recover(); p != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
            panic(p)
        } else if err != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
        } else {
            tx.Commit()
    }()

    param := sql.Named("TVP", mssql.TVP{
        TypeName: "MyTypeName",
        Value:    dtos,
    })

    return tx.ExecContext(ctx, "EXEC [dbo].[usp_InsertConsumption] @TVP", param)
}
```

The test I wrote for this function is included below (note that it depends on ginkgo and gomega):

```
Describe("SQL Tests", func() {

    It("AddConsumption - No failures - Added", func() {

        db, mock, _ := sqlmock.New()
        requester := Requester{conn: db}
        defer db.Close()

        mock.ExpectBegin()
        mock.ExpectExec(regexp.QuoteMeta("EXEC [dbo].[usp_InsertConsumption] @TVP")).
            WithArgs("").WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(1, 1))
        mock.ExpectExec(regexp.QuoteMeta("EXEC [dbo].[usp_InsertTags] @TVP")).
            WithArgs("").WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(1, 1))
        mock.ExpectCommit()

        err := requester.doQuery(context.TODO(), generateData())
        Expect(err).ShouldNot(HaveOccurred())
        Expect(mock.ExpectationsWereMet()).ShouldNot(HaveOccurred())
    })
})
```

Now, this code was written for a MySQL context and since I've ported the code over to MSSQL, I've been getting a peculiar error:

```
sql: converting argument with name \"TVP\" type: unsupported type mssql.TVP, a struct
```

It appears that sqlmock is attempting to call `ConvertValue` on the TVP object, which is invalid. So, how do I make sqlmock handle this value correctly so I can unit test around the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I discovered here is that sqlmock has a function called `ValueConverterOption`, accepts an implementation of the `driver.ValueConverter` interface. This will be used in place of the standard function for every invocation of `ConvertValue`. If you want to test around the `ExecContext` function when it receives a non-standard argument, a TVP in this case, then you can use this function to inject custom conversion logic into sqlmock.

```
type mockTvpConverter struct {}

func (converter *mockTvpConverter) ConvertValue(raw interface{}) (driver.Value, error) {

    // Since this function will take the place of every call of ConvertValue, we will inevitably
    // the fake string we return from this function so we need to check whether we've recieved
    // that or a TVP. More extensive logic may be required
    switch inner := raw.(type) {
    case string:
        return raw.(string), nil
    case mssql.TVP:

        // First, verify the type name
        Expect(inner.TypeName).Should(Equal("MyTypeName"))

        // VERIFICATION LOGIC HERE

        // Finally, return a fake value that we can use when verifying the arguments
        return "PASSED", nil
    }

    // We had an invalid type; return an error
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("Invalid type")
}
```

which means, the test then becomes:

```
Describe("SQL Tests", func() {

    It("AddConsumption - No failures - Added", func() {

        db, mock, _ := sqlmock.New(sqlmock.ValueConverterOption(&mockTvpConverter{}))
        requester := Requester{conn: db}
        defer db.Close()

        mock.ExpectBegin()
        mock.ExpectExec(regexp.QuoteMeta("EXEC [dbo].[usp_InsertConsumption] @TVP")).
            WithArgs("PASSED").WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(1, 1))
        mock.ExpectExec(regexp.QuoteMeta("EXEC [dbo].[usp_InsertTags] @TVP")).
            WithArgs("PASSED").WillReturnResult(sqlmock.NewResult(1, 1))
        mock.ExpectCommit()

        err := requester.doQuery(context.TODO(), generateData())
        Expect(err).ShouldNot(HaveOccurred())
        Expect(mock.ExpectationsWereMet()).ShouldNot(HaveOccurred())
    })
})
```